# Silverlight in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, silverlight

#### Duplicate:

[How do I use Silverlight from ASP.NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/737705/how-do-i-use-silverlight-from-asp-net)

How do I add some Silverlight content to an already created ASP.NET website?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/737705/how-do-i-use-silverlight-from-asp-net.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a new Silverlight application to your existing solution. Here's an [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc838260(VS.95).aspx) which shows how to integrate it with your existing website, so building the Silverlight application will deploy the Silverlight control to your ASP.NET website's Client_Bin folder.

To add a Silverlight control to a webpage in your site, you can reference the Silverlight test page that's automatically created for you, or you can use the [ASP:Silverlight control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc838274(VS.95).aspx), which will take care of loading the Silverlight object.

Answer (score 0):

You only need to copy the XAP file to your site and reference it.

When you create a blank SL project you get the boiler plate code for the ASp .net site for free.

- Having an ASP .net 3.5 SP1 enabled site, you can asp:Silverlight control:
- Going without any ASP .net sugar control (you can use it on ie an php page), you can use an Object intance inside a div:

Soirry tried to paste code samples but didn't work well :-(.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft does not recommend using the ASP:Silverlight control as of Silverlight 3.

There's a great article at MSDN about how to include Silverlight using the `<object>` tag, or using the silverlight.js library: [Integrating Silverlight with a Web Page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc838145%28VS.95%29.aspx).  This helped clear up a lot of confusion for me.

This makes it much easier to provide a more customized experience that fits in better with the rest of your application.

(There's also a decent article explaining how to interact with the Silverlight control once it's embedded in your page: [HTML Bridge: Interaction Between HTML and Managed Code](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645076%28VS.95%29.aspx))